# Why this Action Method is not receiving any value from the form?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, stored-procedures

How to pass some value from the form to the controller using the **FormCollection** method. But the **controller return null**.And the form is located inside a modal popup window..

**View**

```html
<form action="/Home/AddToCart" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="vid" name="vid" class="hiddenid" />
    <div class="styled-input agile-styled-input-top">

        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" id="name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="styled-input">

        <input type="text" placeholder="Star Name" name="star" id="star" required>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Add To Cart">

</form>
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddToCart(FormCollection data) {

    var cart = new cart {
        vid = Convert.ToInt32(data["vid"]),
        name = data["name"],
        star = data["star"]
    };
    userService.AddToCart(cart);
    ViewBag.p = userService;
    return RedirectToAction("Temple");
}
```

Comment: Please provide a little more information. Can you check your browser's dev tools to see whether the browser sent the values in the HTTP POST? When you say "the controller does not receive any value", do you mean that AddToCart is not invoked, or that it is invoked but the data doesn't appear to have the posted values? How did you check whether the values made it into the action: did you set a breakpoint and inspect the `data`? Or are you assuming nothing was there for some other reason? Did you get an exception? If so, what was the error message?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior     AddtToCart is invoked. I tried by using breakpoint but inside the parameters no value id detected

Comment: What parameters are included in the HTTP POST coming out of your browser?